# Curl Script pipe output

Tags: curl

```
for url in `cat urlList_sample.txt`; do
curl $url >> urlsOut.txt;
echo "" >> urlsOut.txt;
done
```

Using the code above to look a bunch of URL's in a text document, all on there own line.

Two questions:

1. how do I get my script to add quotes to beginning and end of the url before calling curl?
2. how do I get in my urlsout.txt file the URL it curled plus the response? Currently I'm only getting the response. I would prefer it to be url curled ^ response

Hi all sorry, just getting back to this issue, can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

To add quotes add a line

```
url="\""$url"\"";
```

but then curl is taking the leading quote as part of the protocol and url-catch will fail.

If the url to catch contains e.g. white space it may be appropriate to use

```
urlencode $url
```

The urlencode program can be installed with

```
sudo apt-get install gridsite-clients
```

To get a roof sign and the catched url as postfix of the url data:

```
curl -w ^%{url_effective} $url >> urlsOut.txt;
```

Comment: `for url in `cat urlList_sample.txt`; do
url="\""$url"\"";
curl -wv ^%{url_effective} $url >> urlsOut.txt;
done`

resultes in, curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host '^%url_effective'

Comment: looks like in my urlsout.txt it put only one set of quotes around all the URL's not each one individually